# How to call database function using AdonisJS?

Tags: postgis, adonis.js

I’ve got a database in PostgreSQL containing GeoData,
and I need to invoke PostGIS functions such as ST_AsGeoJSON, ST_AsText etc. using the lucid ORM but can’t seem to find a way around.

Can anybody provide me with any example or docs related to it ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try `Database.raw()`? https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/query-builder#_raw_queries

Comment: Yes, raw queries work just fine, but it would be better if I could use ORM.

Comment: `.query().raw()` doesn't work. You can try something like : `await User.query().select(Database.raw('ST_AsGeoJSON(...)')).fetch();`.